# How to find words containing a certain letter with Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find any words containing the letter "y".

This was my idea:

```
/\bw*[y]\w*\b/
```

a word boundary, something or nothing, y, something or nothing, word boundary.
It works for the first word, but not for the next one.

How do I get all the words containing a y within a string?

Comment: What language are you using? Can you please add a tag to your question for the language?

Answer (score 14):

maybe try this:

```
[a-zA-Z]*y[a-zA-Z]*
```

This finds all words that have the letter 'y'.

I hope I helped. I tested it on http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 13):

Not knowing what language you're using and guessing based on the syntax of your attempt, this should work:

```
/\b\w*[Yy]\w*\b/g
```

Without the ["g" (for "global") option](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) you'll only get the first match. Note also this matches on "y" in both upper and lower case.