# Regex to find words with specific character

Tags: c#, regex

How to find all words which contain a specific letter in it?

For example, if my string is

```
This is a Station called South Yarra
```

then I want to extract all words with the letter 'a' in them. The matches will be

```
"a", "Station", "called", "Yarra"
```

So far I have tried

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w[a]\w");

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s[a*]\s");
```

Comment: "Specific **digit**"?  Did you mean "specific **letter**"?  *Digit* usually means a number from 0 to 9.

Comment: Yes I mean letter. Corrected my wording

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find words containing a certain letter with Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924693/how-to-find-words-containing-a-certain-letter-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with below regular expression

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^\s]*[a][^\s]*");
```

Comment: Be careful, the match will extend into punctuation too. Consider `\w*a\w*` as an alternative that matches word characters only.

Comment: You are right @Wyck. It's not clear from question whether it is expected to have punctuation in the words or not , and what should be expectation in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without regex using Linq :

```
List<string> arr = s.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Contains('a')).ToList();
```

[`string.Split(' ')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) : It return array of strings that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by ' '

[`Enumerable.Where(predicate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) : Filter sequence based on predicate

[`Enumerable.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8) : Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element

POC: [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kokV1d)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to handle punctuation such as hyphenation, consider using just `\w*a\w*`.

FYI: `\w` matches a *word* character.