# Regex Replace Words Containing Specified Substring

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

I am trying to replace words in my string that contain a certain substring. Here is an example

```
import regex as re

given_in = 'My cat is not like other cats'
desired_out = 'My foo is not like other foo'
```

I have tried

```
print(re.sub('cat', 'foo', given_in))
>>>> 'My foo is not like other foos'
```

and

```
print(re.sub('.*cat.*', 'foo', given_in))
>>>> 'foo'
```

What is the right approach here?

Comment: In samples that easy, maybe just use `\w*cat\w*`?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\w*cat\w*', 'foo', in)` or `re.sub(r'\bcat\w*', 'foo', in)`, see [How to find words containing a certain letter with Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924693/how-to-find-words-containing-a-certain-letter-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
import re

given_in = 'My cat is not like other cat'
desired_out = 'My foo is not like other foo'

out = re.subn("\w*(cat)\w*", "foo", given_in)
print(out)
```

output:

```
'My foo is not like other foo'
```